# Purpose of "this" in Kotlin classes

Tags: class, kotlin, this, getter-setter

I'm trying to work out the purpose of `this` in classes. Consider the following example:

```
class TestMe {

    var a: Int = 1
    var b: Int = 2

    fun setValA(value: Int) {
        this.a = value
    }
    fun setValB(value: Int) {
        b = value
    }
}

val testInstance1 = TestMe()
val testInstance2 = TestMe()

testInstance1.setValA(3)
testInstance1.setValB(4)

println("instance 2A: ${testInstance2.a}, instance 2B: ${testInstance2.b}") // 1 2
println("instance 1A: ${testInstance1.a}, instance 1B: ${testInstance1.b}") // 3 4
```

It seems that I can simply omit `this` value and the results will be the same. Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, same as Java, but you will have a problem if `a` is the parameter name also:

```
fun setValA(a: Int) {
    a = a
}
```

Compilation error:

```
Val cannot be reassigned
```

Then you will have to use `this`:

```
fun setValA(a: Int) {
    this.a = a
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to user7294900's answer, `this` can only be omitted in `this.<property or method name>`, and there are plenty of other uses: e.g. `this::class`, or

```
fun doSomething(other: OtherClass) {
    other.doSomethingWith(this)
}
```